# Meteor IOS Websocket issue

Tags: ios, meteor, websocket, localhost

Ios app suddenly started to fail to load resources from localhost like image files.

When I kill the app and open it again it works fine. But when I screen lock the phone and then open it again it starts to give `Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server.` 
for http://localhost:12184/some.jpg.

And also
`Connection timeout. No sockjs heartbeat received.
http://localhost:12184/`

I have try to add
`BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll("http://meteor.local");`
but it didn't work.

Do you have any idea what might be the problem?

Versions:
`Meteor 1.5.2.1 Xcode 9`

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi apparently it was an issue about the `cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp` plugin.
Just take a a look at this fix and it will resolve the issue.

https://github.com/grundmanise/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp/commit/9a414d8